# Flows - Cloning a flow without multiple iteration - am I doing it right?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.flow

I am just starting to familiarize myself with Kotlin flows.

For this, I am using them to parse the contents of a binary file which I will simulate using the following flow:

```
fun testFlow() = flow {
    println("Starting loop")

    try {
        for (i in 0..5) {
            emit(i)
            delay(100)
        }

        println("Loop has finished")
    }
    finally {
        println("Finally")
    }
}
```

Now, I need the file contents multiple times basically to extract different sets of information.
However, I don't want to read the file twice, but only once.

As there doesn't seem to be a built-in mechanism to clone / duplicate a flow, I developed the following helper function:

```
interface MultiConsumeBlock<T> {
    suspend fun subscribe(): Flow<T>
}

suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.multiConsume(capacity: Int = DEFAULT_CONCURRENCY, scope: CoroutineScope? = null, block: suspend MultiConsumeBlock<T>.() -> Unit) {
    val channel = buffer(capacity).broadcastIn(scope ?: CoroutineScope(coroutineContext))

    val context = object : MultiConsumeBlock<T> {
        override suspend fun subscribe(): Flow<T> {
            val subscription = channel.openSubscription()
            return flow { emitAll(subscription) }
        }
    }
    try {
        block(context)
    } finally {
        channel.cancel()
    }
}
```

which I then use like this (think about the analogy to the file: flow `a` gets every record, flow `b` only the first 3 records (="file header") and flow `c` everything after the header):

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val src = testFlow()

    src.multiConsume {
        val a = subscribe().map { it }
        val b = subscribe().drop(3).map{ it + it}
        val c = subscribe().take(3).map{ it * it}

        mapOf("A" to a, "B" to b, "C" to c).map { task -> launch { task.value.collect{ println("${task.key}: $it")} } }.toList().joinAll()
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Starting loop
A: 0
C: 1
A: 1
C: 2
A: 4
C: 3
A: 9
C: 4
A: 16
C: 5
B: 10
C: 6
B: 12
C: 7
B: 14
C: 8
B: 16
C: 9
B: 18
C: 10
B: 20
C: 11
Loop has finished
Finally
```

Which looks good so far.
However, am I am unsure if I am using Kotlin's flows correctly in this regard.
Am I opening myself up for Deadlocks, missed Exceptions etc.?

[The documentation just states](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/#):

> All implementations of the Flow interface must adhere to two key properties described in detail below:
>
> - Context preservation.
> - Exception transparency.

But I am unsure if that's the case for my implementation or if I am missing something.
Or maybe there is a better way alltogether?

Comment: I am not that familiar with Flows either (at least in production), but ... this smells strange to me. Why not parse the file once and store the results post-processing so your real flows are based upon pre-processed data. Or is this not the use case? (I'm also interested in hearing what the use case is).

Comment: @MartinMarconcini: The files are 10GB+ each and contain records (for simplification: Just imagine a line-delimited file), so just loading them into memory is not feasible. Therefore, the concept of flows "streaming" the data through my application seems very interesting to me. However, at multiple times, I need some records in multiple "ways" (think about: Some records are like "headings" describing other reports in more detail). So using flows, I am trying to different sorts of parsing at the same time basically, requiring me to "clone" the Flow basically. Hope that explaination helps.

Comment: Or even a simpler example: Let's say I am parsing a log file line by line which contains messages of different severity (INFO, WARN and ERROR). Now all the INFO need to be in one Flow and all the WARN and ERROR in another flow. But I haven't really found a way to (conditionally) create two flows out of one without the source being evaluated multiple times (i.e. the file being opened multiple times). On the other hand, flows seem to add multiple advantages (backpressure, cancellable, ...), so I would really like to use them instead of plain Sequences.

Comment: There is a plan to provide an out-of-the box mechanism for such sharing in the future. See https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1261

Comment: @Matthias I see; makes sense. If memory is then a concern, perhaps something around Okio could work too but at this point, I don't think Flow is comparable to the power of RX in this particular case so perhaps considering RX for this case is not that crazy, considering it would be _relatively_ easy to remove in the future if the Flow api allows for something like this. But maybe someone smarter can think of something better. Sorry :/